# StackView Horizontal Images - Maintain same images width if hidden

Tags: swift, scrollview, uistackview

Let say, I have a horizontal ScrollView of 20 (110 * 130 point) UIViews contained within a StackView.  Each UIView will contain an image and a label.
If I decide to hide certain UIViews from the StackView it changes/stretches the width of the UIView.
How would I be able to maintain the same width/height of the UIView?
So lets say if I decided to hide 19 UIViews contained within the StackView.  Is it possible to only show 1 UIView (110 * 130) within the StackView?

I have tested this out using a StackView of 3 UIViews in Storyboard with no success.
If I get this to work then my plan is to programmatically code in the 20UIViews.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **constraints** for the **views inside the stack view**. So in your case, the width constraint isn't set for the UIViews and is therefore causing weird problems.

I recommend checking out this guide on working with stack views in storyboard : http://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro/

Comment: Thanks very much.  This has worked very well.  I have another problem with moving the visible images so that they are side by side.  I have raised another question.  If you have time to look at.  Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659979/move-visible-images-in-stackview-closer-to-leading-space